# Android take Photo and load the aviary SKD

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, mediastore, aviary

I am trying to [learning aviary SDK](https://developers.aviary.com/)  , I have downloaded their [sample](http://d1wufgde20uhiw.cloudfront.net/sdk/android/Aviary-Android-Sample-App.zip).

What I want to do is to Take a Photo using :

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
 startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 }
```

and load the picture just taken into the aviary skd:
their sample says to use:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent( this, FeatherActivity.class );
newIntent.setData( Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/32705") );
newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET, "your api secret" );
startActivityForResult( newIntent, 1 );
```

But if I just taken the Picture using the Intent, I dont yet have the image Uri correct ?

Really all I want is to take a photo and load it direct into their Photo editing SDK.

Here is the code so far, using their sample. Thanks guys

```
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private String mApiKey;

    private static final int ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY = 99;
    private static final int ACTION_REQUEST_FEATHER = 100;
    private static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_UNAVAILABLE = 1;

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

...
        mEditButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                if ( mImageUri != null ) {
                    startFeather( mImageUri );
                }
            }
        } );

        mImageContainer.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
            /*  Uri uri = pickRandomImage();
                if ( uri != null ) {
                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "image uri: " + uri );
                    loadAsync( uri );
                } */

                // TODO add here to load camera 

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }




            }// end onClick
        } );






        mImageContainer.setLongClickable( true );
        mImageContainer.setOnLongClickListener( new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick( View v ) {
                if ( mImageUri != null ) {
                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onLongClick: " + v );
                    openContextMenu( v );
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } );

        Toast.makeText( this, "launcher: " + getLibraryVersion() + ", sdk: " + SDKUtils.SDK_VERSION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT )
                .show();

        mGalleryFolder = createFolders();
        registerForContextMenu( mImageContainer );

        // pre-load the cds service
        Intent cdsIntent = AviaryIntent.createCdsInitIntent( getBaseContext(), API_SECRET, null );

        startService( cdsIntent );

        new ApiKeyReader().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onResume" );
        super.onResume();

        if ( getIntent() != null ) {
            handleIntent( getIntent() );
            setIntent( new Intent() );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu( ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo ) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu( menu, v, menuInfo );
        menu.setHeaderTitle( "Menu" );
        menu.add( 0, 0, 0, "Details" );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {

        final int order = item.getOrder();
        switch ( order ) {
            case 0:
                showCurrentImageDetails();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected( item );
    }

    private void setApiKey( String value ) {
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "api-key: " + value );
        mApiKey = value;

        if( null == value ) {
            String message = SDKUtils.MISSING_APIKEY_MESSAGE;
            new AlertDialog.Builder( this ).setTitle( "API-KEY Missing!" ).setMessage( message ).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the incoming {@link Intent}
     */
    private void handleIntent( Intent intent ) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if ( null != action ) {

            if ( Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals( action ) ) {

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if ( extras != null && extras.containsKey( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM ) ) {
                    Uri uri = (Uri) extras.get( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM );
                    loadAsync( uri );
                }
            } else if ( Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals( action ) ) {
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                Log.d( LOG_TAG, "data: " + data );
                loadAsync( data );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the incoming Image
     * 
     * @param uri
     */
    private void loadAsync( final Uri uri ) {
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "loadAsync: " + uri );

        Drawable toRecycle = mImage.getDrawable();
        if ( toRecycle != null && toRecycle instanceof BitmapDrawable ) {
            if ( ( (BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap() != null )
                ( (BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap().recycle();
        }
        mImage.setImageDrawable( null );
        mImageUri = null;

        DownloadAsync task = new DownloadAsync();
        task.execute( uri );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onDestroy" );
        super.onDestroy();
        mOutputFilePath = null;
    }

    /**
     * Load the image details and pass the result
     * to the {@link ImageInfoActivity} activity
     */
    private void showCurrentImageDetails() {
        if ( null != mImageUri ) {
            ImageInfo info;
            try {
                info = new ImageInfo( this, mImageUri );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            if ( null != info ) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( this, ImageInfoActivity.class );
                intent.putExtra( "image-info", info );
                startActivity( intent );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a file without throwing any exception
     * 
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    private boolean deleteFileNoThrow( String path ) {
        File file;
        try {
            file = new File( path );
        } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( file.exists() ) {
            return file.delete();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();

        mGalleryButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 );
        mEditButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button2 );
        mImage = ( (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.image ) );
        mImageContainer = findViewById( R.id.image_container );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {

        Intent intent;

        final int id = item.getItemId();

        if ( id == R.id.view_documentation ) {
            intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            intent.setData( Uri.parse( "http://www.aviary.com/android-documentation" ) );
            startActivity( intent );
        } else if ( id == R.id.get_sdk ) {

            intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            intent.setData( Uri.parse( "https://github.com/AviaryInc/Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-Android" ) );
            startActivity( intent );
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch ( id ) {
        // external sdcard is not mounted!
            case EXTERNAL_STORAGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( this ).setTitle( R.string.external_storage_na_title )
                        .setMessage( R.string.external_storage_na_message ).create();
                break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * This method is called when feather has completed ( ie. user clicked on "done" or just exit the activity without saving ). <br />
     * If user clicked the "done" button you'll receive RESULT_OK as resultCode, RESULT_CANCELED otherwise.
     * 
     * @param requestCode
     *  - it is the code passed with startActivityForResult
     * @param resultCode
     *  - result code of the activity launched ( it can be RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELED )
     * @param data
     *  - the result data
     */
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            switch ( requestCode ) {
                case ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY:
                    // user chose an image from the gallery
                    loadAsync( data.getData() );
                    break;

                case ACTION_REQUEST_FEATHER:

                    boolean changed = true;

                    if( null != data ) {
                        Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
                        if( null != extra ) {
                            // image was changed by the user?
                            changed = extra.getBoolean( Constants.EXTRA_OUT_BITMAP_CHANGED );
                        }
                    }

                    if( !changed ) {
                        Log.w( LOG_TAG, "User did not modify the image, but just clicked on 'Done' button" );
                    }

                    // send a notification to the media scanner
                    updateMedia( mOutputFilePath );

                    // update the preview with the result
                    loadAsync( data.getData() );
                    onSaveCompleted( mOutputFilePath );
                    mOutputFilePath = null;
                    break;
            }
        } else if ( resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) {
            switch ( requestCode ) {
                case ACTION_REQUEST_FEATHER:

                    // feather was cancelled without saving.
                    // we need to delete the entire session
                    if ( null != mSessionId ) deleteSession( mSessionId );

                    // delete the result file, if exists
                    if ( mOutputFilePath != null ) {
                        deleteFileNoThrow( mOutputFilePath );
                        mOutputFilePath = null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * lo-res process completed, ask the user if wants to process also the hi-res image
     * 
     * @param filepath
     *           lo-res file name ( in case we want to delete it )
     */
    private void onSaveCompleted( final String filepath ) {

        if ( mSessionId != null ) {

            OnClickListener yesListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                    if ( null != mSessionId ) {
                        processHD( mSessionId );
                    }
                    mSessionId = null;
                }
            };

            OnClickListener noListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {

                    if ( null != mSessionId ) {
                        deleteSession( mSessionId );
                    }

                    if ( !isFinishing() ) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    mSessionId = null;
                }
            };

            Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( this ).setTitle( "HiRes" )
                    .setMessage( "A low-resolution image was created. Do you want to save the hi-res image too?" )
                    .setPositiveButton( android.R.string.yes, yesListener ).setNegativeButton( android.R.string.no, noListener )
                    .setCancelable( false ).create();

            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Given an Uri load the bitmap into the current ImageView and resize it to fit the image container size
     * 
     * @param uri
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private boolean setImageURI( final Uri uri, final Bitmap bitmap ) {

        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "image size: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight() );
        mImage.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
        mImage.setBackgroundDrawable( null );

        mEditButton.setEnabled( true );
        mImageUri = uri;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * We need to notify the MediaScanner when a new file is created. 
     * In this way all the gallery applications will be notified too.
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    private void updateMedia( String filepath ) {
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "updateMedia: " + filepath );
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile( getApplicationContext(), new String[] { filepath }, null, null );
    }

    /**
     * Pick a random image from the user gallery
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Uri pickRandomImage() {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ImageColumns._ID, ImageColumns.DATA },
                ImageColumns.SIZE + ">?", new String[] { "90000" }, null );
        Uri uri = null;

        if ( c != null ) {
            int total = c.getCount();
            int position = (int) ( Math.random() * total );
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "pickRandomImage. total images: " + total + ", position: " + position );
            if ( total > 0 ) {
                if ( c.moveToPosition( position ) ) {
                    String data = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex( Images.ImageColumns.DATA ) );
                    long id = c.getLong( c.getColumnIndex( Images.ImageColumns._ID ) );

                    // you can pass to the Aviary-SDK an uri with a "content://" scheme
                    // or an abolute file path like "file:///mnt/..." or just "/mnt/..."

                    // using the "content:/" style uri
                    // uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf( id ) );

                    // using the file scheme uri, passing the real path
                    uri = Uri.parse( data );

                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, uri.toString() );
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
        return uri;
    }

    /**
     * Return the current application version string
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private String getLibraryVersion() {
        String result = "";

        try {
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo( getPackageName(), 0 );
            result = info.versionName;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {}

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Return a new image file. Name is based on the current time. Parent folder will be the one created with createFolders
     * 
     * @return
     * @see #createFolders()
     */
    private File getNextFileName() {
        if ( mGalleryFolder != null ) {
            if ( mGalleryFolder.exists() ) {
                File file = new File( mGalleryFolder, "aviary_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" );
                return file;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Once you've chosen an image you can start the feather activity
     * 
     * @param uri
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void startFeather( Uri uri ) {

        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "uri: " + uri );

        // first check the external storage availability
        if ( !isExternalStorageAvilable() ) {
            showDialog( EXTERNAL_STORAGE_UNAVAILABLE );
            return;
        }

        // create a temporary file where to store the resulting image
        File file = getNextFileName();


        if ( null != file ) {
            mOutputFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder( this ).setTitle( android.R.string.dialog_alert_title ).setMessage( "Failed to create a new File" )
                    .show();
            return;
        }

        mSessionId = StringUtils.getSha256( System.currentTimeMillis() + mApiKey );
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "session: " + mSessionId + ", size: " + mSessionId.length() );
        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_OUTPUT_HIRES_SESSION_ID, mSessionId );


        newIntent.putExtra( Constants.EXTRA_IN_SAVE_ON_NO_CHANGES, true );

        // ..and start feather
        startActivityForResult( newIntent, ACTION_REQUEST_FEATHER );
    }

    /**
     * Check the external storage status
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isExternalStorageAvilable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Start the activity to pick an image from the user gallery
     */
    private void pickFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
        intent.setType( "image/*" );

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose a Picture" );
        startActivityForResult( chooser, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY );
    }

    /**
     * Try to create the required folder on the sdcard where images will be saved to.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private File createFolders() {

        File baseDir;

        if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8 ) {
            baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        } else {
            baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );
        }

        if ( baseDir == null ) return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Pictures folder: " + baseDir.getAbsolutePath() );
        File aviaryFolder = new File( baseDir, FOLDER_NAME );

        if ( aviaryFolder.exists() ) return aviaryFolder;
        if ( aviaryFolder.mkdirs() ) return aviaryFolder;

        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    }

    /**
     * Start the hi-res image processing.
     * 
     */
    private void processHD( final String session_name ) {

        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "processHD: " + session_name );

        // get a new file for the hi-res file
        File destination = getNextFileName();

        try {
            if ( destination == null || !destination.createNewFile() ) {
                Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Failed to create a new file" );
                return;
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Log.e( LOG_TAG, e.getMessage() );
            Toast.makeText( this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            return;
        }

        String error = null;

        // Now we need to fetch the session information from the content provider
        FeatherContentProvider.SessionsDbColumns.Session session = null;

        Uri sessionUri = FeatherContentProvider.SessionsDbColumns.getContentUri( this, session_name );

        // this query will return a cursor with the informations about the given session
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( sessionUri, null, null, null, null );

        if ( null != cursor ) {
            session = FeatherContentProvider.SessionsDbColumns.Session.Create( cursor );
            cursor.close();
        }

        if ( null != session ) {
            // Print out the session informations
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "session.id: " + session.id ); // session _id
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "session.name: " + session.session ); // session name
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "session.ctime: " + session.ctime ); // creation time
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "session.file_name: " + session.file_name ); // original file, it is the same you passed in the
                                                                                                // startActivityForResult Intent

            // Now, based on the session information we need to retrieve
            // the list of actions to apply to the hi-res image
            Uri actionsUri = FeatherContentProvider.ActionsDbColumns.getContentUri( this, session.session );

            // this query will return the list of actions performed on the original file, during the FeatherActivity session.
            // Now you can apply each action to the hi-res image to replicate the same result on the bigger image
            cursor = getContentResolver().query( actionsUri, null, null, null, null );

            if ( null != cursor ) {
                // If the cursor is valid we will start a new asynctask process to query the cursor
                // and apply all the actions in a queue
                HDAsyncTask task = new HDAsyncTask( Uri.parse( session.file_name ), destination.getAbsolutePath(), session_name );
                task.execute( cursor );
            } else {
                error = "Failed to retrieve the list of actions!";
            }
        } else {
            error = "Failed to retrieve the session informations";
        }

        if ( null != error ) {
            Toast.makeText( this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete the session and all it's actions. We do not need it anymore.<br />
     * Note that this is optional. All old sessions are automatically removed in Feather.
     * 
     * @param session_id
     */
    private void deleteSession( final String session_id ) {
        Uri uri = FeatherContentProvider.SessionsDbColumns.getContentUri( this, session_id );
        getContentResolver().delete( uri, null, null );
    }

    /**
     * AsyncTask for Hi-Res image processing
     * 
     * @author alessandro
     * 
     */
    private class HDAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Cursor, Integer, String> {

        Uri uri_;
        String dstPath_;
        ProgressDialog progress_;
        String session_;
        ExifInterfaceExtended exif_;

        /**
         * Initialize the HiRes async task
         * 
         * @param source
         *           - source image file
         * @param destination
         *           - destination image file
         * @param session_id
         *           - the session id used to retrieve the list of actions
         */
        public HDAsyncTask( Uri source, String destination, String session_id ) {
            uri_ = source;
            dstPath_ = destination;
            session_ = session_id;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress_ = new ProgressDialog( MainActivity.this );
            progress_.setIndeterminate( true );
            progress_.setTitle( "Processing Hi-res image" );
            progress_.setMessage( "Loading image..." );
            progress_.setProgressStyle( ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER );
            progress_.setCancelable( false );
            progress_.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate( Integer... values ) {
            super.onProgressUpdate( values );

            final int index = values[0];
            final int total = values[1];
            String message = "";

            if ( index == -1 )
                message = "Saving image...";
            else
                message = "Applying action " + ( index + 1 ) + " of " + ( total );

            progress_.setMessage( message );

            Log.d( LOG_TAG, index + "/" + total + ", message: " + message );
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground( Cursor... params ) {
            Cursor cursor = params[0];

            if ( null != cursor ) {

                // IMPORTANT NOTE:
                // If in your manifest you're using a different process for the FeatherActivity Activity
                // then you *MUST* call this method before using any of the MoaHD methods, otherwise
                // you will receive a java exception
                try {
                    NativeFilterProxy.init( getBaseContext() );
                } catch ( AviaryInitializationException e ) {
                    return e.getMessage();
                }


                // Initialize the class to perform HD operations
                MoaHD moa = new MoaHD();

                // Premium partners only: 
                //  by default the maximum image size for hi-res is set to 13Mp ( is fixed to 3mp for the free version of the sdk )
                moa.setMaxMegaPixels( MegaPixels.Mp15 );

                boolean loaded;
                try {
                    loaded = loadImage( moa );
                } catch ( AviaryExecutionException e ) {
                    return e.getMessage();
                }

                // if image is loaded
                if ( loaded ) {

                    final int total_actions = cursor.getCount();

                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "total actions: " + total_actions );

                    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {

                        // get the total number of actions in the queue
                        // we're adding also the 'load' and the 'save' action to the total count

                        // now for each action in the given cursor, apply the action to
                        // the MoaHD instance
                        do {
                            // send a progress notification to the progressbar dialog
                            publishProgress( cursor.getPosition(), total_actions );

                            // load the action from the current cursor
                            Action action = Action.Create( cursor );
                            if ( null != action ) {
                                Log.d( LOG_TAG, "executing: " + action.id + "(" + action.session_id + " on " + action.ctime + ") = "
                                        + action.getActions() );

                                // apply a list of actions to the current image
                                moa.applyActions( action.getActions() );
                            } else {
                                Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Woa, something went wrong! Invalid action returned" );
                            }

                            // move the cursor to next position
                        } while ( cursor.moveToNext() );
                    }

                    // at the end of all the operations we need to save
                    // the modified image to a new file
                    publishProgress( -1, -1 );

                    try {
                        moa.save( dstPath_ );
                    } catch ( AviaryExecutionException e ) {
                        return e.getMessage();
                    } finally {
                        moa.dispose();
                    }

                    // ok, now we can save the source image EXIF tags
                    // to the new image
                    if ( null != exif_ ) {
                        saveExif( exif_, dstPath_ );
                    }

                } else {
                    return "Failed to load the image";
                }

                cursor.close();

                // and unload the current bitmap. Note that you *MUST* call this method to free the memory allocated with the load
                // method

                if( moa.isLoaded() ) {
                    try {
                        moa.unload();
                    } catch ( AviaryExecutionException e ) {}
                }

                if( !moa.isDisposed() ) {
                    // finally dispose the moahd instance
                    moa.dispose();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Save the Exif tags to the new image
         * 
         * @param originalExif
         * @param filename
         */
        private void saveExif( ExifInterfaceExtended originalExif, String filename ) {
            // ok, now we can save back the EXIF tags
            // to the new file
            ExifInterfaceExtended newExif = null;
            try {
                newExif = new ExifInterfaceExtended( dstPath_ );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if ( null != newExif && null != originalExif ) {

                // save the original exif tags to a Bundle object
                Bundle out = new Bundle();
                originalExif.copyTo( out );

                // import the exif tags from the original file 
                newExif.copyFrom( out, true );

                // this should be changed because the editor already rotate the image
                newExif.setAttribute( ExifInterfaceExtended.TAG_EXIF_ORIENTATION, "0" );
                // let's update the software tag too
                newExif.setAttribute( ExifInterfaceExtended.TAG_EXIF_SOFTWARE, "Aviary " + SDKUtils.SDK_VERSION );
                // ...and the modification date
                newExif.setAttribute( ExifInterfaceExtended.TAG_EXIF_DATETIME, ExifInterfaceExtended.formatDate( new Date() ) );
                try {
                    newExif.saveAttributes();
                } catch ( IOException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String errorString ) {
            super.onPostExecute( errorString );

            if ( progress_.getWindow() != null ) {
                progress_.dismiss();
            }

            // in case we had an error...
            if ( null != errorString ) {
                Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "There was an error: " + errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                return;
            }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figured out.

I just use the Android Intend :

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
```

and in the **onActivityResult**

```
case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                // user chose an image from the gallery
                loadAsync( data.getData() );
                break;
```

I grab the result.